# How to use for loop in karate

Tags: karate

I have an array `* def prices = [
  1104.57,
  1189.57,
  1784.57,
  1274.57,
  1487.07
]`

I want to traverse all the elements of this array and assert that all elements in this array is number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
* match each prices == ‘#number’
```

please read the docs for ‘match each’

Comment: Thanks @peter.I will go through the documentation again.